# building a class from an existing one

Tags: python, pandas, inheritance

I am trying to build a class from pandas DataFrame. I just want to add an attribute 'name' to DataFrame class. But the codes below yield errors in recursion maximum depth reached. Which way to make it work? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
class DatFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, name, data=None, index=None, columns=None,
                 dtype=None, copy=False):
        self.name = name
        pd.DataFrame.__init__(self, data=None, index=None, 
                              columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)


x = array([[9, 7, 5],
          [7, 3, 1],
          [8, 8, 3],
          [7, 4, 3]])
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
index = ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

s = DatFrame('huy', x, index, cols)
```

Error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: Just so you know, you can dynamically add attributes to Python objects. So, let's say you have a `pd.DataFrame` referenced by variable `df`, then you can just do `df.name = 'huy'`

Comment: Also, there are special considerations when subclassing `pandas` data structures. See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you're passing `None` to all parameters of your dataframe

Second, the fix it is to call the `__init__` method first, before setting `name`.

It's probably because the `pd.DataFrame` object expects an empty variable dictionary when initializing (recursion occurs in `__getattr__`), and your `name` member confuses it:

```
class DatFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, name, data=None, index=None, columns=None,
                 dtype=None, copy=False):
        pd.DataFrame.__init__(self, data=data, index=index,
                              columns=columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
        self.name = name
```

As a general rule, it's always better to call the parent constructor first thing, *then* set your specifics.

As comments said, if it's only to add `name` (without adding methods) you could create a factory method that adds dynamically the attribute, no need to inherit:

```
def create_datframe(name,*args,**kwargs):
    r = pd.DataFrame(*args,**kwargs)
    r.name = name
    return r
```

Comment: Yeah, while I can see the merits of subclassing when you want to add attributes, in this case, because subclassing `pd.Dataframe` is non-trivial, I might just go with dynamic attributes. And definitely, looking at the stack-trace of the recursion error, there is some magic going on with properties and names, which makes sense, since you can access columns by name as attributes in data-frames. Having a non-empty `__dict__` could definitely mess up whatever complicated initialization is going on.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga AFAIK subclassing to add attributes or dynamically adding attributes has the same effect. The class `__dict__` is updated (externally or within `__init__`), so it doesn't change a thing, except by the way it is initially built.