# How can I inherit defaultdict and use its copy method in subclass method?

Tags: python, inheritance, collections, copy, defaultdict

There is the code.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class A(defaultdict):
  def __init__(self):
    super(A, self).__init__(lambda :0)
    self.x = 1

  def my_copy(self):
    return self.copy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  a = defaultdict(lambda :0)
  b = a.copy() # no error when using the base class directly
  a = A()
  b = a.my_copy()
```

There is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1591, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1018, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
   exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/liu/project/scir/pytorch_test/t.py", line 14, in <module>
    b = a.my_copy()
  File "/Users/liu/project/scir/pytorch_test/t.py", line 8, in my_copy
    return self.copy()
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I don't know how to inherit the copy method and also don't know why I give 3 argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When calling `copy`, `defaultdict` invokes a constructor with arguments, to pass the `default_factory` function and the data.

Your constructor doesn't take any arguments, so it's only able to build empty dicts with fixed factory.

Fix your constructor like this:

```
def __init__(self,*args):
```

But you have to pass `args` to the mother class or your copied dictionary will be empty (not that you want).

Since you're specializing the default factory, you have to make a special case if `args` are empty:

```
class A(defaultdict):
  def __init__(self,*args):
    if args:
        super(A, self).__init__(*args)
    else:
        super(A, self).__init__(int)  # better than lambda : 0
```

Or maybe simpler with a ternary:

```
class A(defaultdict):
  def __init__(self,*args):
    super(A, self).__init__(*(args or (int,)))
```

- When `args` is not empty (called from `copy`), then the copy takes properties of the original (function & data).
- When `args` is empty, it means that you're creating a new dict, so it just fixes the default factory argument.

Aside: you could replace `(lambda :0)` by `(int)`.

EDIT: a more complicated way but which makes sure that user cannot change default would be to ignore first argument and force `int` (maybe with a warning if first argument isn't `int`):

```
super(A, self).__init__(*([int]+list(args[1:])))
```

That would work, but I don't like the idea of ignoring an argument much.

As a conclusion, inheriting for built-in types in general is tricky and should be used with caution (see another example trying to do that with a `pandas` dataframe: [building a class from an existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382585/building-a-class-from-an-existing-one/45382657#45382657)). Sometimes creating a class with a `defaultdict` as argument, and which mimics/relays only the methods you're planning to use will lead to less side-effects.

Comment: This let the user specify a different factory, which might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers see my edit. But my conclusion is: it's tricky to inherit safely from a built-in type.

Answer (score 5):

I decided to expand what was a small comment to an answer. While a perfect analysis was given in answers already given, I dislike the proposed argument modification. Both defaultdict and the underlying dict have a non-trivial signature (usage of arguments). The code below does not touch the arguments and passes them unchanged to the original implementation:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.default_factory = int
```

Also the kwargs are preserved, e.g. `A(a=1,b=2)` works.

Answer (score 3):

`defaultdict.__init__()` takes three arguments:

1. `self` (of course),
2. An optional factory callable for missing keys, and
3. An optional set of key:values (which and be either a `dict` or a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs).

`defaultdict.copy()` will create a new `defaultdict` instance and pass it it's `factory` callable AND a shallow copy of it's current key:values set.

Your subclass's `__init__` only takes `self` as argument, but ends up being called with three.

The fix here is to rewrite `A.__init__` so it can handle both cases:

```
class A(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # make sure we force the factory
        args = (int,) + args[1:]
        super(A, self).__init__(*args)
```